# Intersection of blocks of the symmetric BIBD $PG(d,q)$

Tags: combinatorial-designs, finite-geometry

The definition of a *Balance Incomplete block design* $(v,k,\lambda)$-BIBD can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBD#Definition_of_a_BIBD_.28or_2-design.29).
It is a well known fact (also see the link above) that every two blocks of a [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBD#Symmetric_BIBDs) $(v,k,\lambda)$-BIBD have exactly $\lambda$ elements in common. I was wondering if the following is also true:

**Guess:** If three distinct blocks of a symmetric $(v,k,\lambda)$-BIBD have at least $2$ elements in common, then they have exactly $\lambda$ elements in common.

Does that hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be true. Consider the following symmetric $(31,15,7)$-BIBD whose incidence matrix is obtained from the 5th tensor power of the matrix $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ by deleting the first row and column, and replacing $-1$ by $0$ everywhere:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0\\
1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0\\
0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1\\
1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0\\
0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1\\
1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1\\
0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0\\
1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0\\
0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1\\
1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1\\
0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0\\
1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1\\
0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0\\
1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0\\
0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1\\
1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0\\
0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1\\
1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1\\
0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0\\
1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1\\
0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0\\
1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0\\
0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1\\
1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1\\
0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0\\
1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0\\
0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1\\
1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0\\
0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1\\
1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1\\
0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!0&\!\!1&\!\!1&\!\!0\end{pmatrix}$$
Observe that e.g. the 4th, 5th and 6th blocks have only 3 points in common (actually, almost any combination contradicts your claim)